# Git integration problems in VSCode with many workspace folders?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I've got about 35 folders in my workspace, all of them git repos, but many of them do not appear to register with VSCode as git repos. Has anyone experienced similar?

Comment: Can you specify what steps you undertook so far?

Comment: I've just opened 30 or so folders in the workspace, and many of them do not appear as git repositories (e.g. no green circles on untracked files), even though they are git repositories. If I open a new workspace and add one or two is it okay, but with many it appears not.